# Selenium 3.3.0 with GeckoDriver 0.11.0 crashes in location property

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

A bunch of our tests started failing today after Selenium 3.3.0 release with following error:

```
@property
def location(self):
    """The location of the element in the renderable canvas."""
    if self._w3c:
        old_loc = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_RECT)['value']
    else:
        old_loc = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_LOCATION)['value']
```

> ```
>   new_loc = {"x": round(old_loc['x']),
>                "y": round(old_loc['y'])}
> ```
>
> E       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:403: TypeError

Versions of packages/software:

- selenium 3.3.0
- pytest-selenium 1.9.1
- geckodriver 0.11.0

Question:

1. any other way to address this except for downgrading selenium to
   3.0.2?
2. looks like a bug, but I'm not sure where to file it, GeckoDriver issue tracker?

PS: I know it's a very old version of GeckoDriver, update is not an option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 3.3.0 requires geckodriver 0.15 due to changes in command response values